# How was this javascript class outline produced in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am updating documentation for a project and need to update the javascript class diagrams. I have no idea how they were produced:

[image]

Comment: Removed the C# tag since nothing in the question indicated a relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they used the js-addin

https://code.google.com/p/js-addin/